# How to write a sql query to find completion rate from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table named assigned which includes two field namely task_idXXXStatus.I want to find the completion rate which is nothing but the count of rows in the table when filtered for status=complete divided by the total number of rows in the table * 100. Here's the sample table below:

[image]

Comment: Please post what you have tried, the table layout via a creation script and even some sample data perhaps.  Your text says "complete" but your example does not. Please be clear and precise in your question.

Comment: What are the implications of having one task_id value that is both of "completed" and "Not Completed" status? Is there a third field in this table that you need to consider that has (perhaps) a date and time? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple method:

```
select avg(case when status = 'Complete' then 100.0 else 0.0 end) as rate
from t;
```

This uses average, which is a tad simpler than summing the completes and dividing by the total.

You could actually phrase this as a `join` rather than `case` expression as well:

```
select avg(coalesce(v.val, 0.0)) as rate
from t left join
     (values ('Complete', 100.0)) v(status, val)
     on v.status = t.status
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 100.0*SUM(IIF(Status='Complete',1, 0)/NULLIF(COUNT(*),0) AS ratio
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the rows with `status = 'Completed'` by conditional `sum`:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE status WHEN 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

If i go by step by step easy explanation via your query

```
            Select * from
            ( (( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE 
             WHERE STATUS 
          ='Completed` ) /
            (SELECT COUNT(Distinct *) FROM TABLE))*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what the implications are when the same `task_id` has more than one `status`?

Like **111**? It shows both "completed" and "not completed".

Perhaps there is a third column in this table that needs to be considered that has a date and time value?

This version of the answer copes with any "status" value...

```
CREATE table my_table
(
task_Id int NOT NULL,
task_status varchar(50) NOT NULL,
);    

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(111, 'Not Completed');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(129, 'Completed');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(111, 'Completed');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(135, 'Not Completed');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(136, 'Not Completed');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(137, 'Not Completed');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(119, 'Completed');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(112, 'Not Completed');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(118, 'Completed');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(126, 'Not Completed');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(777, 'In Process');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(888, 'In Process');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(999, 'Waiting for something');


WITH s1 -- JJAUSSI: count the distinct list of task_id values
AS
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.task_id) as task_count_total
  FROM my_table t
)
SELECT t.task_status
      ,CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT t.task_id) AS decimal)/CAST(s1.task_count_total as decimal) as task_status_percent_of_total
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT t.task_id) as task_status_count
      ,s1.task_count_total      
  FROM my_table t
  CROSS JOIN s1
 GROUP BY t.task_status
        ,s1.task_count_total
 ORDER BY 1;
```

I used a simple Common Table Expression there.

This article has more on [Common Table Expressions](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/).

These are the results...

```
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|    |      task_status      | task_status_percent_of_total | task_status_count | task_count_total |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|  1 | Completed             |        0.3333333333333333333 |                 4 |               12 |
|  2 | In Process            |        0.1666666666666666666 |                 2 |               12 |
|  3 | Not Completed         |        0.5000000000000000000 |                 6 |               12 |
|  4 | Waiting for something |        0.0833333333333333333 |                 1 |               12 |
+----+-----------------------+------------------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

I created the ASCII table using [this tool](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). Hope this helps get you started.